Gazebo runs slow on VirtualBox
I'm new to gazebo but I've noticed it runs very slowly on my Virtual Machine (Virtual Box). Is there a way to improve it? It does 1.3 fps.

Everything which requires a dedicated GPU (e.g. Gazebo rendering) to achieve a high FPS rate runs very slowly in VirtualBox. This is due to the lack of support for GPU passthrough in VirtualBox. Instead VirtualBox emulates a generic virtual GPU and is therefore not suitable for tasks that require or benefit from a direct access to a dedicated GPU.
It looks like there was experimental support for PCI (no PCIe!) passthrough for VirtualBox 6.0 but it has been removed for 6.1.
If you have to use Windows (instead of a dedicated Linux machine which I'd always recommend!) you might have a look at WSL2.

There are other virtual machine packages out there, I was able to do that with some minor setup in virtual machine manager. There are plenty of tutorials on youtube for all kinds of setups.
